# My current activity get crashes while i am updating my value using hash map in firebase

Tags: android

I want to update my data in firebase database using Hashmap but when i do it first time it crashes my activity . i don't know whats the reason behind that.

I tried every possible way like getting the database reference and storage reference on activity start means in OnStart() function but it didn't work.

```
private void updateProfile(String fullname, String username, String bio) {

    DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());


    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("fullname",fullname);
    hashMap.put("username",username);
    hashMap.put("bio",bio);


    reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Data upload sucessfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Output should be like my Activity should not crash.

This is the change at first time when i change my data first time.

```
2019-09-03 16:59:21.472 5112-5112/? I/leanchitkaraap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
```

2019-09-03 16:59:21.520 5112-5126/com.example.cleanchitkaraapp I/leanchitkaraap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-09-03 16:59:21.707 5112-5112/com.example.cleanchitkaraapp I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-09-03 16:59:21.770 5112-5112/com.example.cleanchitkaraapp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2019-09-03 16:59:21.780 5112-5145/com.example.cleanchitkaraapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2019-09-03 16:59:21.797 5112-5112/com.example.cleanchitkaraapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2019-09-03 16:59:21.801 5112-5147/com.example.cleanchitkaraapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: can you post crash log

Comment: that log is not related to your crash. Please find and post the crash log

Comment: @akshar_shahane  Bro i noticed my log cat when i click on save button first the the above changes are there in the log cat no changes at all different that the log cat.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  Bro i noticed my log cat when i click on save button first the the above changes are there in the log cat no changes at all different that the log cat.

Comment: @akshay_shahane